# ReferenceError admin-firebase node.js

Tags: nodejs, firebase, firebase-messaging

estoy tratando de subir un archivo js que me envié una notificación push.
El problema es que me arroja el siguiente error en consola:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at (index):4
```

En esa linea de codigo se encuentra:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

Realice todos los pasos que me indicaba para añadir el sdk de firebase, mi hosting es el que brinda firebase, pero no encuentro como solucionar.

Comment: Suena un poco tonto pero has instalado el administrador de Firebase como indica su documentación? Estás trabajando desde algún framework o desde NodeJs?

Answer (score 0):

`require()` no existe en el navegador/cliente. Para importar paquetes desde directo en el front-end podrías hacerlo con la etiqueta `<script>`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

O utilizando alguna herramienta como [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)

Si quieres desarrollar la lógica de las notificaciones en el back-end, echa un ojo a [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).